# Nothing selected in Select by default - how to fix that?

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, drop-down-menu

I'm using Angular 5 and I have a simple Select:

```
  <select class="ui fluid dropdown" formControlName="device">
    <option *ngFor="let device of getSenderDevices()" [ngValue]="device">{{device.Name}}</option>
  </select>
```

My problem is the fact that by default nothing is selected, but I'd like the first option to be selected. I saw many threads like this, the solution that I thought would work, does not:

```
  <select class="ui fluid dropdown" formControlName="device">
    <option *ngFor="let device of getDevices(); let i = index" [ngValue]="device" [selected]="i==0">{{device.Name}}</option>
  </select>
```

I also found some advices to use compareWith directive - but I wasn't able to understand how it works.

Maybe the problem is caused by getDevices(), which returns data with some delay, because the data is fetched from external server. In the beginning select has to be empty, because the data is not ready yet. When it arrives however, I'd like the select to show that by auto-selecting first option.

Comment: you're writing [ngValue]="device", that's to the whole object, you only need give to "device" the first element of getDevices() -in pseudo-code getDevices()[0]-. Or, as tell Sajeetharan, use [value].device.Name and equal to -in pseudo-code- getDevices()[0].Name

Comment: @Eliseo Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood. [ngValue]="device" lets me get the selected device by the whole object, which is better for me than getting only Name for example. Can you explain to me more your proposed solution?

Comment: ok, I put an answer, I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Not use a function getDevices() and not use [selected] in .html

```
//I imagine you have a serviceData that return an observable
export class DataService {
    constructor(private httpClient HttpClient) {}
    public getDevices():Observable<any>
    {
          return this.httpClient.get("....");
    }
}

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private myservice:ServiceData){}
ngOnInit()
{
     this.myService.getDevices().subscribe(res=>{
            this.devices=res;
            this.createForm();
     })
     //If getDevices() simple return an array, not from service
     //   this.devices=getServices();
     //   this.createForm();
}
createForm()
{
   this.myForm=this.fb.group({device:this.device[0]})
}
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<select class="ui fluid dropdown" formControlName="device">
    <!--NOT use [selected], when "device" get the value, the select show the value-->
    <!--I use the variables "devices"--->
    <option *ngFor="let device of devices; let i = index" 
          [ngValue]="device">{{device.Name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```